# what shall I do about this ground meat?

Tags: ground-beef

I left some ground meat in the refrigerator on a plate uncovered for 2 days, would it still be good to use it doesn't look like there is anything wrong with it? Answer asap please.

Comment: Duplicate: [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21069/23376)

Comment: If it was starting to oxidize gray or smell funny, I would brown it in a pan (like for spaghetti or tacos) and not use it for hamburgers.

Answer (score 2):

Ground meat is safe for [1 - 2 days in the fridge](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21069/23376). Ground meat is prone to spoil fast due to the larger surface per unit of measure compared to non-ground meat.